# Getting an object's attribute from an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSDictionary with NSString as some of the values and some of the other values are my own classes.  My question is how to access the attributes of one of my classes from the dictionary.  My assumption is this:

```
dictionary[@"work"].name
```

will get the work object from the dictionary and then the name attribute from the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YourClass *classVar = [self.yourDictionary objectForKey:@"work"];
classVar.name = @"your name";
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer with an explanation of what this does and _why_ it works?

Answer (score 0):

Generally that will work, but not directly with dot syntax because the compiler doesn't know what type of object is in the dictionary (it's returned as `id`), so you would need to cast. If you call the `name` method using the old syntax it should be fine (the compiler trusts that it will be ok).